# Trigger job from a notebook in Azure databricks

Tags: parameters, triggers, databricks, jobs, spark-notebook

I have a job that accepts date as parameter. I need to pass yesterday's date as parameter to the job and schedule it. But we can't send yesterday's date(dynamic parameter) when it is scheduled. So I created a notebook **(say N2)** on top of this and I am passing the calculated yesterday's date to the main notebook as a parameter. But I want to trigger the job created on this main notebook from the notebook N2. How can I do that?

If there is a way to do this kindly help me.

Comment: Just for clarity, can you not calculate yesterday's date in the notebook itself ? Or maybe take a widget to pass value, check widget value, if it is empty use current date - 1, or else use the value from the widget ?

Comment: @rainingdistros I don't want to do in this way (there are some reasons for that). Is there any way to trigger a job from notebook.